# making a discord bot print coloured text using the css code format

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi i have a simple bot that takes a command:

````
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def test(ctx, *lines):
    print("repeating")
    coloured_lines=[]
    for line in lines:
        coloured_lines.append("```css \n"+ line + "```")
    await asyncio.gather(*[ctx.send(line) for line in coloured_lines])
````

You write to it a command like $repeat "green text is cool", and you should get an output like:

[image]

instead you get [image]. My intuition is that this is because something is happening with the ` character - although i am not sure what, or how to fix it.

Comment: weirdly if you remove the lines of code that put line into a css code area, and then ask the bot to repeat something thats already in the css area it comes out fine.

Comment: In markdown text[`code block`] each spaces will be on count! and the first line of the `code block` text says what kind of text it is! So, you must just type "css" without any single space at end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```` coloured_lines.append("```css \n"+ line + "```") ```` In markdown space's count and `css`  is not a valid file format and `css` is. ```` coloured_lines.append("```css\n"+ line + "```") ````

[What you expect and what you got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq70J.png)
[What you did wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G21QH.png)